# How to install no latest but highest version of npm package without specifying a version

Tags: github, npm

For some reason when I do npm publish the registry does not remove `latest` tag from previous version and does not attach `latest` to newer version.

I there a way to download highest version of package without knowing exactly what the version is?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [semantic versioning](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning) if you aren't already. You can use [this tool](https://semver.npmjs.com/) to see examples of how version spec works. Here's an example that could be included in [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json) which will install the highest version of lodash in the registry:

```
"dependencies": {
  "lodash": "x"
}
```

Comment: I does not work. It install latest version no the highest one.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I do not know how to install highest version. But I localized a error in npm, if I publish my package when in package.json is `"depraceted":false` it will not change tag to latest even if I pass it as flag in publish command.